# function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed>

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I got a lot of crashes like this
`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of App.CACountryDetectionViewController.receivedWhereAmI (App.CACountryDetectionViewController)(ObjectiveC.NSNotification) -> ()
in CACountryDetectionViewController.swift, line 62`

Stacktrace:

- `function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of App.CACountryDetectionViewController.receivedWhereAmI (App.CACountryDetectionViewController)(ObjectiveC.NSNotification) -> () (CACountryDetectionViewController.swift:62)`
- `@objc App.CACountryDetectionViewController.receivedWhereAmI (App.CACountryDetectionViewController)(ObjectiveC.NSNotification) -> () (CACountryDetectionViewController.swift:0)`
- `__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16`
- `__37-[CAManager postNotification:object:]_block_invoke (CAManager.m:95)`

CACountryDetectionViewController.swift

```
    internal func receivedWhereAmI(notification: NSNotification) {
      if let response = notification.object as? CAWhereAmIResponse {
          whereAmIState = .Finished
          defaultCity = response.cities?.objectForKey(response.country.defaultCity) as? CACity // 62
          setCountry(response.country)
      } else {
          failedToReceiveWhereAmI()
      }
    }
```

viewDidLoad:
`addObserver("receivedWhereAmI:", name: CACountryManagerReceivedWhereAmINotification)`

deinit: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)`

Can somebody explain to me what happened?

Comment: what line is 62 in your code

Comment: @Yarneo `defaultCity = response.cities?.objectForKey(response.country.defaultCity) as? CACity // 62`

Answer (score 0):

I get these errors all the time too. It is usually better to check what the exception was. In your case I am assuming it should be:

```
"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

I think the issue is probably with response.country.defaultCity
It is safe to assume response isn't nil due to the if unwrapping statement. But response.country could be nil, or response.country.defaultCity, which then could throw an exception.